# ASP.NET session variable is wrong after multiple click event fast

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have an asp.net website to manage projects. I realized that when I click for the next project really fast and often it overrides all the next projects with the data of the first one. I call a method to save before to go for the next project. I use also a session variable for the id of the project.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the sever stacks the save method and the ids but keeps the values of the first project in the controls

Am I right?

this is the ajax that calls a server method to get the id and set it in an hidden field:

```
function NextClick() {
            var tabvalue = $("#<%=TabsToFocus.ClientId%>").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Projet.aspx/NextProj",
                    data: "{tab:'" + tabvalue + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(d) {
                        if (d.d != "False") {
                            $("#<%=hid_selProjetID.ClientID%>").val(d.d);
                            var btn = $("#<%=btnClickLstProjet.ClientID%>");
                            fillHidden();
                             btn.click();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

And btn.click() calls this method on the server side to save

```
Private Sub Button1_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClickLstProjet.ServerClick

    If HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("isUser") IsNot Nothing AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("isUser") = True Then
        If HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("curProjetID") IsNot Nothing Then

            btnSaveIndicateurs_Click()
            btnSaveEnTete_Click()
            btnSaveGen_Click()
            btnSavePlanif_Click()
        End If
    End If

    HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("curProjetID") = hid_selProjetID.Value
    Response.Redirect("Projet.aspx")

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Show your code where you handle the click event and set the session variable.

Comment: 1 sec plz it's coming. I try to make it more readable and simple. My code is in french

Comment: In asp.net the Session object is "locked" by the request using it. If a second request arrives while the first on is still executed, the second request will wait for the first one to finish before it can gain access to the session object. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I don't understand why it overrides all my projects then

Comment: What does your `NextProj` method do? WebMethods are static, that means shared by  all requests. I assume that you've to look there to find the source of your problem. @Johnny5: That applies only to requests from the same user, what actually here is applicable since the user clicks the button multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I realized that I did a mistake in my question. Can you give a look again plz. The session is good I think. Cause all projects are override with the values of the first one, so the id changes

Comment: @Johnny5: That's misleading.  Session is write locked when the page starts writing to it.  It's not read locked at all.  The second request will not wait until it gets to the point of writing the session object and by then it's too late because all the queries have already ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is **STOP using session**.

Seriously, back away from the session object.

A proper use of session is long term, fairly unchanging data.  Data that has to change on literally every post back etc belongs in the page itself.

---

Here is what's happening.

1. You click on a link to load up the project.  The Session variable is being set with the current project id.
2. You then click on a link to get the next project,
3. Then quickly click on the link to get the one after that.

The server, meanwhile, is multithreaded.  #3 basically interupted #2's execution.. and ran before #2.  This means your session variable is jacked up.

Why would the 3rd request run before the 2nd?  Well, you are executing a number of queries.  It's likely that the queries for request 2 are taking slightly longer to exec than the ones for request 3.

Solution: Stop using Session.

Why: You cannot predict the order in which IIS is going to respond to requests.  IIS is a parallel (not serial) engine and requests might very well happen out of the sequence you think they should.

Finally, the guy who said that session is locked by the first requestor wasn't entirely accurate.  It is WRITE locked.. but that only occurs when the page starts writing to session.  Reads are not locked.

So, when request 3 executes it is using the ID of request 1, or 2.  Depending on which one is still active by the time it hits the write code.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand more how it works! I wish I could stop using the session but my boss doesn't want... So I disable the control to change project while it's loading...